# Assembly uses 'System.Runtime' Version=4.2.2.0 which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' Version=4.1.2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project that reference a .NET Core 3.1 library. The problem is that I get this error:

*Error  CS1705  Assembly 'X' with identity 'X, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'*

In NuGet Manager for both projects, I have tried to add System.Runtime 4.3.1. Still I get the same error. How can this be fixed?

Comment: I don't think .NET 4.7 projects can access .NET Core libraries.  Someone please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It should go, see here:

https://benjaminray.com/codebase/entity-framework-core-model-in-net-framework-4x-project/

"Because .NET Standard is implemented by later versions of the .NET Framework and .NET Core, these two very different project types can actually play nicely together. (I think of .NET Standard like an interface implemented by .NET Framework and .NET Core.) For example, a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project can use .NET Core 3.1 features, or reference a .NET Core 3.1 libraries."

Comment: Is the library `.NET Standard` though?

Comment: The library is .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Library would have to be .NET Standard.

Comment: But, I think I need to run .NET Core 3.0 to send Apns notification with p12 certificate. That is what my .NET Core 3.1 project does...

Ref: 
It is easy to send Apple Push Notification. You don't need any GitHub libraries or Nuget packages. I use this simple function. It only depends on API from .Net Core 3.0.